# Expiration date reminder

Tags: android, productivity, reminders

I'm looking for an Android app that can remind me of the upcoming expiration dates of items such as passport, insurance, coupons, or even shelved food.

**Requirements:**

- Ability to enter an item name, the expiry date, and the relative reminder period (e.g. 1 month before expiration)
- Some sort of cloud backup for the resulting database, or at least the capability to export to/import from SD card in a common file format (`csv`, `html`,...)
- Reminders via email/SMS or some other permanent record, not just through notifications
- Works on Android 5

**Great to have:**

- An accompanying web app
- Categories and tags for entries
- Reccurring reminders until action is taken
- Android widget for quick add
- Single payment purchase (no subsription)

Comment: The reminder via email/SMS will likely be the hardest requirement to meet.

Comment: A little list: [Shopping Receipts](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_receipts) (some including warranty reminders, which can be used for any "expiration reminders"). I've never used any of them, so I cannot give a recommendation ;)

Comment: @Izzy I read through their features, but none of them have email reminders, or backup ([Warranty Reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ci.warranty.warrantyreminder) has it on their upcoming features)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.lifehacker.co.in/life/FoodKeeper-Tells-You-When-Food-Really-Expires-Sends-You-Reminders/articleshow/46881101.cms) post on [lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.co.in), the post is about an app named [FoodKeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gov.usda.fsis.foodkeeper&hl=en)([iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/usda-food-safety-inspection/id439084578)), which tells you when your food really expires and sends you reminder, this app uses the information which comes from [USDA](https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/usda-food-safety-inspection/id439084578).

this might help you.

Comment: Thanks. But that looks like just a collection of tips about food. I can't input manual entries. It's a nice app, just not what I'm looking for